# How to change an attribute of an Array of objects with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I want to change the  percentage attribute for each object
I tried using `Array.map()` to loop through each object and use a `setState(prevState => {return {...prevState, percentage: newValue}})` inside the `Array.map()`, But clearly this is incorrect and I don't know how to change the value of this attribute for each object

This is the Array of objects

```
interface Data {
  state: string;
  value: number;
  percentage: number;
}

const [data, setData] = useState<Data[]>([
{
  state: 'SP',
  value: 67836.66,
  percentage: 0
},
{
  state: 'RJ',
  value: 36678.66,
  percentage: 0
},
{
  state: 'MG',
  value: 29229.88,
  percentage: 0
},
{
  state: 'ES',
  value: 27165.48,
  percentage: 0
},
{
  state: 'Outros',
  value: 19849.53,
  percentage: 0
},

])
```

Comment: Do you want them *all* to be the same percentage? What are you doing to calculate the percentage for each item?

Comment: @JoelHager each object has a different percentage `let tot = 0         data.map(item => tot += item.value)         data.map(item => (item.value * 100) / tot)` will be something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reduce first to get the total, and then apply the calculation in another loop.

Resource on reducers (to accumulate a total through an array)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

```js
const list = [
  {
    state: 'SP',
    value: 67836.66,
    percentage: 0
  },
  {
    state: 'RJ',
    value: 36678.66,
    percentage: 0
  },
  {
    state: 'MG',
    value: 29229.88,
    percentage: 0
  },
  {
    state: 'ES',
    value: 27165.48,
    percentage: 0
  },
  {
    state: 'Outros',
    value: 19849.53,
    percentage: 0
  },
]

// Where we compute the total
let total = list.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // console.log(acc, item)
  return acc += item.value
}, 0)

// Where we apply the percentages (note: map also works)
list.forEach((item) => item.percentage = ((item.value / total) * 100).toFixed(2))

// If you add them up, you get 100 (percent)
console.log(list)
```